# How to configure rabbitmq docker in an asp.net core solution?

Tags: linux, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, rabbitmq

being new in the field I try to configure rabbitmq on a solution, after research I learned that I could either do it online directly or use docker, for a start I chose to do it with docker desktop I I created an asp.net.core api and a C# console application, then I created a rabbitmq image using the command "docker pull rabbitmq:3-management" and I launched it via the command "docker run — rm -it -p 15672:15672 -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management" and in docker I end up with a rabbitmq container, in visual studio I had docker supported and had a dockerfile which I didn't I haven't touched, and when I run the solution it generates another container for me with a randomly generated port but which is not accessible, does anyone have a solution for me?

I tried to delete the docker-compose and even the dockerfile that was generated so that it no longer has to generate a docker image for me but I only get error after error

Answer (score 0):

You installed RabbitMQ server in docker then it can be used with this port. You don't have run the project with docker support. Just use normal Kestrel mode to run will be fine.

To use RabbitMQ in asp.net core , you can reference this [starter tutorial](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-dotnet.html)

Only HostName need to be configured generally.

```
var factory = new ConnectionFactory { HostName = "localhost" };
```

You can change localhost to RabbitMQ IP.